# How filter on listgrid using smartgwt

Tags: smartgwt

How can I remove the arrow down in the folter of the last column?.

I have this:

```
listGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
listGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true);
listGrid.setFilterOnKeypress(true);
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Button filterButton = new Button();
filterButton.setVisible(false);
grid.setFilterButtonProperties(filterButton);
```